# js render loop that breaks once a condition is met

Tags: javascript, loops, html, canvas

How do I set up a setInterval render loop that breaks, once a condition is met?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can store the interval ID and clear it via [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval), for example

```
var timer = setInterval(myFunction, 1000);

function myFunction() {
  if(condition) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    return;
  }
  //do stuff
}
```

Or if you can just call `clearInterval()` where setting the condition, so the next interval doesn't run, having no logic for this in the function itself.

Answer (score 8):

[`clearInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) stops the repetition from `setInterval`, using the ID returned by `setInterval`:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    // do your loop
    if (loop_should_stop) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, dt);
```

Comment: This would result in it running one last time before stopping, the check needs to be at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Yes. Depending on where the break condition is calculated, this might bewhat you want.

Answer (score 2):

Nick's answer works perfectly. I extended it by returning a promise

```
function checkUntil(conditionFunc, millisecondsInterval) {
    var retryCount = 0;
    var retryCountLimit = 100;

    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var timer = setInterval(function () {
            if (conditionFunc()) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                resolve();
                return;
            }
            retryCount++;
            if (retryCount >= retryCountLimit) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                reject("retry count exceeded");
            }
        }, millisecondsInterval);
    });

    return promise;
}
```

and you can invoke it like so

```
checkUntil(function () {
        return document.querySelector('body');
    }, 500).then(function () {
          ...
          ...
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you ask on how to stop a function call that has been set using setInterval(), just use the [clearInteval() function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp).
You first have to save a reference to the setInterval function and than use this reference to stop the interval:

```
var int=self.setInterval("your_function_name()",1000);
if(condition){
    clearInterval(int)
}
```

Comment: Yes, but **don't** use a string, use the actual function reference.

Answer (score 0):

Improving on @aTable 's answer using 2022 Javascript:

```
function waitUntil(conditionFunction, millisecondsInterval) {
  const retryCountLimit = 10;
  let retryCount = 0;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (conditionFunction()) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        resolve();
      }

      retryCount++;

      if (retryCount >= retryCountLimit) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        reject(new Error('WaitUntil() retry count exceeded'));
      }
    }, millisecondsInterval);
  });
}
```

And it can be invoked with:

```
await waitUntil(document.getElementById('SOME_ID'), 500);

// do stuff
```